# Unlimited For loops

Tags: vb.net, loops

I want to run something like this:

```
For a = 0 To 4
   For b = a To 4
      For c = b To 4
        Console.WriteLine(a & b & c)
      Next
   Next
Next
```

But I need to create n loops one each other. So I created this method:

```
'iFrom = 0; iTo = 4; Depth = 3(loop count);
Private Sub Iterate(ByVal iFrom As Integer, ByVal iTo As Integer, ByVal Depth As Integer)
    For i = iFrom To iTo
       If Depth - 1 > 0 Then Iterate(iFrom, iTo, Depth - 1)

       'Do stuff here
    Next
End Sub
```

What would be the best way to retrieve the "i" values from higher levels? Should I store them in an array? Or is there a completely different way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this method I finally found the solution. Here it is:

```
Private Sub Iterate(ByVal iFrom As Integer, ByVal iTo As Integer, ByVal Depth As Integer, ByVal iValues As Integer())
    For i = iFrom To iTo
        iValues(Depth - 1) = i
        If Depth - 1 > 0 Then
            Iterate(i, iTo, Depth - 1, iValues)
        Else                
            'Do stuff, in this case print the current iValues
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", iValues.Select(Function(x) x.ToString).ToArray))                
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub

'Usage:
Dim iValueArray(Depth) As Integer
Iterate(0, 1, 2, iValueArray)
```

Comment: You should move the `If` outside the loop, because `Depth` does not change from iteration to iteration. This change would take you to the standard layout of recursive functions that I described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an array or similar structure as parameter to `Iterate()` and for each call to `Iterate()` you add the current value of `i` to the array.

Thus you could know the depth of your loop and the current value of the "parent" loop.